# Extjs multi select treepicker

Tags: extjs

I have a treepicker in my form and I need to select multiple items from its store. Is there any way to do this like a combo box's `multiSelect:true`?

```
{
    xtype: 'treepicker',
    store: groupStore,
    autoScroll: true,
    selectOnTab: true,
    name: 'propertyPicker',
  //multiSelect: true
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField: 'id',
    queryMode: 'local',
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any such option in the documentation for TreePicker.

However if you have the flexibility to use a different component, a CheckTree may better suit your task: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/tree/check-tree.html

[image: ExtJS 4 Check Tree]

The linked example only has leaves as checkboxes but adding `checked: false` or `checked: true` so any node will display a checkbox. The following is example JSON used by a store attached to a TreePanel that will show checkboxes for all nodes

```
[{
  "text": "To Do", 
  "cls": "folder",
  "expanded": true,
  "checked": true,
  "children": [{
    "text": "Climb Everest",
    "leaf": true,
    "checked": false
  },
  ...
```

Resulting in:

[image: TreePanel with all nodes as checkboxes]

Comment: this is great but there is still one limit. I need to select root nodes as well as checking combo items. In this example wanna select Grocery list and To Do nodes. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Yes you can have check boxes on non-leaf nodes using this TreePanel too. The checkbox display is based on whether the item in the store as a "checked" attribute. This example is a little better at showing how it works http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/tree/check-tree/viewer.html I'll update the answer with some example JSON to get all entries showing check boxes.